I sent Еthereum to a scammer, need help, please
I am new to cryptocurrencies and like many people before me I sent Ethereum to a scammer. I wanted to revoke the transaction in Debank as I saw in a clip, but I don't have a "profile" in the left menu. The clip is from 1 year ago, maybe it's somewhere else but I can't find it. Is there any other way and can the funds be recovered at all. The address I sent the Ethereum to is 0x83dee5e53470f04bee1149ace5fe5a88e148c94e

Unfortunately, transactions on Ethereum are irreversible. DeBank cannot revoke transactions.
Take preventative measures:

Change your wallet password immediately.
Consider creating a new wallet for future transactions.
Report the scammer (0x83dee5e53470f04bee1149ace5fe5a88e148c94e) like the one mentioned in Ethereum chain scam and how to report and recover crypto

